# TypeError: Failed to convert elements of <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x000001D20E0023E0> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, typeerror

I'm trying to train a neural network to denoise EEG signals. the dimensions of the data changes according to the noise type. This is the code for the training of the network:

```
def train_step(model, noiseEEG_batch, EEG_batch, optimizer , denoise_network, batch_size, datanum):

    mse_grads = 0
    m_loss = 0
      
    with tf.GradientTape() as loss_tape:
    
        M_loss =  0
        for x in range(noiseEEG_batch.shape[0]):
    
            noiseeeg_batch,eeg_batch =  noiseEEG_batch[x] , EEG_batch[x]

            noiseeeg_batch = tf.reshape(noiseeeg_batch, [1,datanum,1]) #datanum=1024
            eeg_batch=tf.reshape(eeg_batch, [1,datanum,1])
            denoiseoutput = Model(noiseeeg_batch)
            #denoiseoutput = tf.reshape(denoiseoutput, [1,datanum,1])                          

            m_loss = denoise_loss_mse(denoiseoutput,eeg_batch)   
            M_loss += m_loss

    
        M_loss = M_loss / float(noiseEEG_batch.shape[0]) 
        
        # calculate gradient
        mse_grads = loss_tape.gradient(M_loss, model.trainable_variables)
        #bp
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(mse_grads, model.trainable_variables))

    return  M_loss,  mse_grads[0]  #EEGloss
```

The network architecture is this.
`

---

#### Layer (type)   |        Output Shape  |  Param

input_12 (InputLayer)    | [(1, 1024, 1)]     |       0

conv1d_70 (Conv1D)       |    (1, 1024, 32)       |     128

conv1d_71 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 1024, 32)       |     3104

average_pooling1d_30 (Avera  |(1, 512, 32)      |       0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_72 (Conv1D)         | (1, 512, 64)        |      6208

conv1d_73 (Conv1D)         | (1, 512, 64)         |     12352

average_pooling1d_31 (Avera | (1, 256, 64)             0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_74 (Conv1D)         | (1, 256, 128)         |    24704

conv1d_75 (Conv1D)         | (1, 256, 128)         |    49280

average_pooling1d_32 (Avera | (1, 128, 128)        |    0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_76 (Conv1D)      |    (1, 128, 256)       |     98560

conv1d_77 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 128, 256)      |       196864

dropout_20 (Dropout)     |   (1, 128, 256)      |       0

average_pooling1d_33 (Avera  | (1, 64, 256)        |     0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_78 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 64, 512)        |      393728

conv1d_79 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 64, 512)         |     786944

dropout_21 (Dropout)     |   (1, 64, 512)       |       0

average_pooling1d_34 (Avera  | (1, 32, 512)      |       0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_80 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 32, 1024)        |     1573888

conv1d_81 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 32, 1024)       |      3146752

dropout_22 (Dropout)     |   (1, 32, 1024)        |     0

average_pooling1d_35 (Avera | (1, 16, 1024)       |     0
gePooling1D)

conv1d_82 (Conv1D)        |  (1, 16, 2048)      |      6293504

conv1d_83 (Conv1D)       |   (1, 16, 2048)      |      12584960

dropout_23 (Dropout)     |   (1, 16, 2048)       |      0

flatten_5 (Flatten)      |   (1, 32768)           |     0

dense_5 (Dense)          |   (1, 1024)           |      33555456

=================================================================
Total params: 58,726,432
Trainable params: 58,726,432
Non-trainable params: 0`

When I try to reshape the eeg_batch for the input, it gives this type error:
TypeError: Failed to convert elements of <keras.engine.training.Model object at 0x000001D20E0023E0> to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.

How can I fix it?